# Branching and merging strategy best practise

Tags: visual-studio, merge

We have two different parallel development going on for the same project in TFS. We have Development and Release branch for new feature development and production deployment respectively.

What should be ideal strategy for Merging and Branching?
Currently we do the production changes in release branch and merge those changes in Development branch. Is this the correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct. Production branch should always be changed when there is a hotfix or bug to be fixed. Otherwise it shouldn't be touched. Do all development in dev branch and merge it into production when dev is tested and considered for release.